# Make an edge list from data

Tags: python, postgresql, graph

I have A huge data and this picture shows some sample of my data:

[image: sample of my data]

I want to make a edge list. If the row value of `column1=column2=column3=column4=column6` are same, there is relation ship (edge) between the row value of column 5 And the result should be like below picture:

[image: Result]

Is there a way to do this? Can postgressSQL or Python or R do that for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a self join:

```
select t1.col5 as vertex_1, t2.col5 as vertex_2
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2 and t1.col3 = t2.col3 and
        t1.col4 = t2.col4 and t1.col6 = t2.col6 and
        t1.col5 <> t2.col5;
```

I cannot tell if you want undirected or directed edges.  If undirected, then change the last condition to:  `t1.col5 < t2.col5`.

Comment: Gordon Linoff Great It works.  Just Could you please explain the reason of writing t1.col5 < t2.col5

Comment: @NeginZarbakhsh . . . When two rows match, if you want only one pair in the output (A-->B), then use `<`.  If you want both (A-->B and B-->A), then use `<>`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is unique elements in your result list. Look at the SQL key words "unique" / "distinct", they can probably be used to generated unique rows.

Comment: @ Ray  I do not want generate unique rows. As you see in the pic the value of some rows in 5 column are equal but these equal value rows are different in column No.4. I want to find way that at first separate these equal rows then make an edge between column No.5. As you see in second Pic, The first 6 rows has same value in 5 column, but  their value in column No.5 are different. Then there should be an edge between them like result Pic